# Can't execute easy_install properly — Couldn't find index page for 'pystache' (maybe misspelled?)

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2

I used to have no issues with dependencies, but now I can't bootstrap. I found a similar issue on [python discussion](https://discuss.python.org/t/pypi-org-recently-changed/8433), but their solution didn't help unfortunately.

```
Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aws_cfn_bootstrap-1.4-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for aws-cfn-bootstrap==1.4
Searching for pystache<0.6.0,>=0.4.0
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pystache/
Couldn't find index page for 'pystache' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for pystache<0.6.0,>=0.4.0
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pystache<0.6.0,>=0.4.0')
```

`easy_install --script-dir /opt/aws/bin aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz`

I also see easy_install will be deprecated in the future release. Anyone else had this issue before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1981333 , pypi.org now requires SSL with the SNI extension and easy_install does not have support for it.